# How to programatically add contents(mail,contacts e.t.c) to NSF File using c#?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I have created some Domino Server Users.
And Now want to progaramaticaly add content to it using c# and Domino.dll.

Note: i did not find any way to manually add content (mails,calendar) of one nsf to another nsf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are specifically looking for how to manually "add content of one nsf to another nsf", you can accomplish this using the CopyToDatabase method of the Document class. The method takes the target database object as its only argument, and returns a Document handle to the new document in that target database.

```
...
    Document doc2 = doc1.CopyToDatabase(db2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Domino.dll exposes a COM interface.
[COM Interop tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx) explains in the first part what needs to be done.